# build the culture of something/ culture building

Tags: word-choice, word-request

In my native language when we want to mean *educating people to do/think the right thing and persuading them to do so in different ways such as advertising, punishment, encouragement, rewards, shaming etc., mostly done in a broad scale*, we say things like these

> It's necessary to **build the culture of** wearing seat belts.
>
> We should wean people off plastic bags and make them use cloth bags instead. I know we can't really force people into this, but we could atleast start its **culture building** in our media!
>
> The necessary **culture building** must be done first before letting the immigrants into the country. People could be really unkind to them because they'd think they came here to take their jobs away.

Interestingly, I can get results for *culture building*, but it seems there's a difference between what I think it should mean and what's there to mean. Do the sentences above read natural to you? If not, is there such a word/phrase to mean that in English? How do you rephrase my sentences?

Comment: Try **create a culture** or **foster a culture**  *We must foster|create a culture where...*

Comment: It is certainly possible to refer to *building a culture*; [there are many books that use that phrase](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&ei=kkVWW5qlOoq7ggf3rrXYCg&q=%22building+a+culture+of%22&oq=%22building+a+culture+of%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...74552.74703.0.74888.3.3.0.0.0.0.99.257.3.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.5CX_2Ahgz34), and it means the same thing that you mean.  But we almost never phrase it as "culture building", for some reason, which makes your 2nd and 3rd sentence sound a little unnatural.  It might read better as *culture-building*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this google ngram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=building+a+culture+of%2C+building+the+culture+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuilding%20a%20culture%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuilding%20the%20culture%20of%3B%2Cc0) the form "building **a** culture of" is moderately frequent, but almost unheard of before about 1985, but "building **the** culture of" is very rare indeed. According to [this related chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=build+a+culture%2Cbuild+the+culture&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbuild%20a%20culture%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuild%20the%20culture%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbuild%20a%20culture%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbuild%20the%20culture%3B%2Cc0) the form 
"build a culture" goes back farther, but "build the culture" is not and never has ben anything but rare.

Your example sentences are understandable, but there are certainly not something i would write myself, and "culture building", like "nation building", to me suggests something some from the outside, or something done by an SF author creating a fictional culture.

I agree with the comment by Tᴚoɯɐuo that "create a culture" or "foster a culture" are more natural expressions in English.